# iFrame issue: Data from the Table is not showing up on the HTML code

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm rather new to web scraping and stack overflow altogether. I'm having trouble scraping information from a website where the table is located in an iframe. What is even more confusing is that the iframe is not a URL. Here is an example:

When I inspect the website, I get:

```html
<iframe src="treeoutagereportpanel ace muni.html">
  <head>...</head>
  <body class="yui-skin-sam">
    <div class="bd">
      <div id="outageReportTree">
        <table id="ygtvtablee11">...</table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</iframe>
```

However, when I connect to the website via JSoup, and test the connection, the table does not appear when I write:

```
    System.out.println(doc.select("html"));
```

or

```
    System.out.println(doc.select("iframe"));
```

(doc is the website's URL)

How would I extract the data from the table in the HTML code if Java did not recognize the table as part of the website?

Comment: HMTL tables defined with <table>, </table> tags.  I think first you have to discern what kind of object you are hunting down.  There are a few tricks to presenting tables on the web, but in HTML that is one way.

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code sorry that was a mistype, I fixed the table tags. I am trying to extract numbers from the table rows, but in order to do that, I first have to make Java identify the table from the website.

Comment: I do not use JSoup but I am going to guess since there can be more than one table on an HTML page/site you are going to have to use, id="ygtvtablee11", in your reference.

Comment: Have you checked that actual response from the server contains this html? Print System.out.println(doc.html());. Maybe the content is loaded via javascript. Jsoup doesn't handle this situation automatically